# CakePhp: create a form which contains information on several models

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, frameworks, model

I've to create a "register" form, this form has to store information in two different database, some fields goes on the local database(login info: username, password)(model named "User") , some in the external database (erp database, which contains email, phone, ...)(Model named "Customer").

We have to do this because of the existing ERP, that we have to use(we have no way to edit this, this is our constraint).

So my question is, how to set a register form which allows us to specify the user and the customer information.

This is not a problem to make the insertion of the "customer" in the "user" controller, I just don't know how to receive a

```
$this->data
```

which contains

```
$this->data['User']
```

and

```
$this->data['Customer']
```

data.

Because in the view, we have to specify which model is used on the "Form" level.

```
echo $this->Form->create('**User**',array('action'=>'register'));
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanna have records like $this->data['User'] and $this->data['Customer'] in your $this->data

your fields of form should be something like this

```
  <?=$form->input('User.email',array('label'=>false));?>
  <?=$form->input('Customer.name',array('label'=>false));?>
  <?=$form->input('User.password',array('label'=>false));?>
```

you have to create realtion between those tables
in model User you have to add this

```
public $hasOne = array("Customer"); //User.customer_id -> Custome.id
```

and you have to use $this->User->saveAll($this->data) to save data in both tables

sorry for my english, and hope it helps you

Comment: Okay, thank you, I didn't know the Model.field password in forms. I'm aware of relations, but because the user and customer table aren't in the same database, is this still possible?

Comment: Tables User and Customer in different database? Is your cakephp application working with two database?

Comment: Yes, and believe me, it's not my choice(the worst thing is that one database is in Ingres and the other one is in MySql). But for now, cake manage the use of two database quite well ;)